# props is undefined although state has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new in react. I have a parent component Navbar, that has state "Total_Item". This array is added on click of Modal. The values are populating. Now  i want to get the length of this array and show on my cart button(presently a simple button), in my Navv component. But it says undefined.

So the data is not saved in props (Tot_Item ) in the Navbar component. I am sure there is some conceptual error how react renders. A clear explanation will really help at this point.

Please see the sandbox below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-sky-cet22

Thanks
sal

Comment: Doesn't look like anything in `Navbar` updates the state at all, so `this.state.Total_Item` that is passed to `Navv` is always the same.

Comment: Drew the Total_Item is appended. I logged it. The problem is passing on the props

Comment: Appended to what? Where? There aren't any `this.setState({ Total_Item: ... })` calls in`Navbar`. `Navbar` simply passes `this.state.Total_Item` to `Navv` and `this.state.Category` to `Menu`. Nothing is updated.

Comment: I did the setState (Total_Item=ll7)in Menu component, using Listval function

Comment: Ok, there are two references (L35 and L43) to some `this.state.Total_Item` in `Menu` but nothing is done with that state from `Menu`. Are you trying to update the state in `Navbar`? On the next line (L45) you `console.log(this.props.Tot_Item)` but that isn't a prop that is passed to `Menu` so I would fully expect it to be undefined. `Navv` has a `Tot_Item` though. Appears you're mixing your logic between the two components.

Comment: Please see this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-curie-t03ey,The this.state.Total_Item: ll7.  This is run in Listval function in Menu. There might be some concept that i m missing, while passing data from child(Menu) to parent(Navbar)

Comment: I can see the `Menu` *also* has a `ListVal` function and this is the one being called in `Menu`. I'm gathering that from the modal you want a user to increment/decrement a quantity and upon closing the modal, use the quantity to update a total back in `Navbar` via `Menu`. Does this sound correct? IMO you have ***way** too many* issues with this code base right now and you're basically asking for them all to be addressed. Please break this problem down into smaller and simpler parts and try to solve each piece individually.

Comment: You are right . The Navbar state, Total_Item has been updated. I used the async/await to see the results using Listval in Menu. I agree there are lot of issues here(some i know and most i m not aware of). The first problem is how to pass he updated state in Total_Item as props? Also i tried to paste Listval function using fat operator, but that did not work for me. So i kept it Menu for time being.

Comment: Passing prop is easy, you're already doing it correctly. Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cdn-f3wx4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FNavbar.jsx&theme=dark) that jumps over the broken code and updates `this.state.Total_Items` value for display in the button in `Navv`. *Note: I had to also kill the style on the OK button in the modal, it wasn't visible otherwise.*

Comment: Thanks Drew. It is indeed passing in as props. "test" is hard coded. Instead of test i kept [] empty aray to begin with. You can see in console.log that Total_item is appended but it shows as 0(length) when passed as props. Please see below:https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-butterfly-otw5j

Comment: You just commented out the function that can update your state in `Navbar`, so it won't update. Passing `Tot_Item={this.state.Total_Item.length}` prop to `Navv` isn't the issue. What ever you are updating or changing in `Menu` isn't getting passed back (via callback) to `Navbar` to update its state, and get passed to `Navv`. They aren't connected. As requested, please try to break your giant problem down into smaller and more manageable pieces and solve each individually. SO isn't a code writing or debugging service.

Comment: Drew I appreciate your time. Let  me work on it and see if i can break it more.

Comment: Drew the solution is below. Thanks for your help and valid points. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `async` and `await` in React, as it's supposed to work asynchronously. **You can, however, pass a callback function to `setState` to do what you want.** That method shall be passed as a second parameter in your `setState` call, and the function you pass will not be run until React has successfully updated the state.

```
this.setState({
  myVar: 'value to print'
}, () => console.log(this.state.myVar));
```

Also, I've noticed you're calling `setState` a lot of times on your `listval` method. You actually don't have to call `setState` multiple times if you want to set many properties at once. Since the state is an object, **you can change all of the properties you want in a single call**, like this:

```
this.setState({
  Select_Price: ll,
  Select_Item: ll3,
  Select_Item_TotalPrice: ll6,
  Total_Item: ll7
});
```

As for why `this.props.Tot_Item` is always `undefined` in your `Navv` component, the reason is that a children component cannot modify its parent' state in any way.

Right now your components are structured in the following way: `Navbar` contains both `Navv` and `Menu`. `Menu` is the one that contains a list of items and is supposed to update the list of selected items, while `Navv` is just supposed to display the number of items in said array.

However, there's a problem: **you cannot pass data directly from `Menu` to its sibling, `Navv`.** It's necessary to have a parent component (in this case, `Navbar`) that gets the data from `Menu` and pass it down to `Navv`. However, it doesn't really work as you have it. **The only way a children component (`Menu`) can alter the parent' (`Navbar`) state is by using a callback method**, as seen in the example below:

- **Changes in `Navbar` component**

```
  // CHANGE: Create callback function to send data to parent
  updateTotalItems = total => {
    this.setState({ Total_Item: total }, () =>
      console.log("total items in navbar", this.state.Total_Item)
    );
  };

  // CHANGE: pass callback method as props to the children component that modifies the item counter
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navv Tot_Item={this.state.Total_Item} />
        <Menu
          updateTotalItems={this.updateTotalItems}
          Objs_Type={this.state.Category}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

- **Changes in `Menu` component**

```
  Listval() {
    /* ... */

    // CHANGE: No need to call setState multiple times
    this.setState(
      {
        Select_Price: ll,
        Select_Item: ll3,
        Select_Item_TotalPrice: ll6,
        Total_Item: ll7
      },
      () => {
        // CHANGE: Use callback function to send the array length to the parent component
        this.props.updateTotalItems(this.state.Total_Item.length);
      }
    );
  }
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-easley-nw63s) you have a working version of your sandbox example with all of these changes. Hope it helps!

Comment: LonelyPrincess, i m in debt. Thank you so much. This is educational for me. Just the kind of answer i was looking for. As you highlighted, every time a child component attempts to alter parent state, it has to be with a call back function. Is this the only way in react? I know you tried to correct my code, could it be any easier /simpler way to achieve this. Just your additional thoughts.

Comment: I'm glad this was useful for you! :)

As for your question, I believe this is the simplest way to do it when you're just getting started. For small application with few components, callbacks should be easy to manage and help you understand how data really flows between components, which can be good to get you started in the React world.

Comment: Of course, for larger projects with a lot of components, using the callback approach can easily get out of hand and make your application a hell to maintain, and in these cases, other alternatives are preferred.

Comment: An alternative is to use libraries such as Redux to implement a global state that can be shared between all components, but I wouldn't recommend it in your case, as it can be pretty hard to understand at first. Once you are more familiar with the basics of React, you may take a look if you're interested. ;)

https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: If you don't want to depend on external libraries, recent versions of React also provide a Context API which can be used to achieve this same thing, so feel free to check it out as well if you have the time. 

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: LonelyPrincess, thanks a bunch.. I plan to learn redux but after some practice on React. One more question, we had call back method to alter state. In my Menu componenet, i am also doing setState for Select_Price, Select_Item etc. But they seem to alter parent state ok. So whats the difference?

Comment: The only difference between Total_Item and the above is that i m pushing updated values in Total_item. I would appreciate if you address this concept.

Comment: You mean that if you call `setState` in `Menu` your parent state is also updated without having to use callbacks? That's not supposed to happen: every component should be responsible of updating its own state. Could you update your sandbox example to take a look at what you're doing? :o

Comment: Thanks, Yes this is what I meant. But i like to know  whats the difference. For example, in the Menu Component we are not using call back function  but using setState for Select_Price and Select_Item. I have updated the sandbox, please see : https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-currying-0b2v6

Answer (score 1):

In file `Navbar.jsx`, value of `this.state.Tot_Item` is empty array. Use `this.setState` function to change the value of `this.state.Tot_Item`
=> In file `Navv.jsx` value of `this.props.Tot_Item` is empty array. Change the way to render an array of button.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rubin-wg2fo

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below changes.

1. You can place your state in constructor.
2. You need to declare ListVal using FAT operator and setState of what you like. (In my case I have explicitly set it to 2 on click of OK button in Modal popup and its appearing on the screen too)

   ```
     import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Menu from "./Menu";
    import Navv from "./Navv";

    class Navbar extends Component {

      constructor(props)
      {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          Category: [
            {
              id: 1,
              FoodType: "Chinese",
              Menu: ["Egg Drop", "Chicken Fried", "Beef Fried"],
              Price: [2, 8, 10]
            },


        {
          id: 2,
          FoodType: "Mexican",
          Menu: ["Veg Burrito", "Chicken Burrito", "Beef Burrito"],
          Price: [7, 8, 10]
        }
      ],

      One_Item: [
        {
          listvalue: null,
          Select_Item: null,
          Select_Price: null,
          Select_Quantity: null,
          Select_Item_TotalPrice: null
        }
      ],

      Total_Item: 0
    };
    }


    Listval=async()=>{
    this.setState({ Total_Item: 2});
    }

    render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navv Tot_Item={this.state.Total_Item} />
        <Menu
           Listvalll={this.Listval}
          Objs_Type={this.state.Category}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
    }
    }
    export default Navbar;
   ```

Comment: Thanks Raghvender. I tried doing what you said, But it seems not to work for me, I tried using fat function, but it gives error.

Comment: Thanks Raghvender., The Total_item is derived from ll7. The problem is the async is not working in Navbar compoonent. Although you addressed theprobelm but that leads to another problem in my code. How to make async funtion work . please see sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-leaf-n5njb

Comment: Why are you using await while doing this.setState ?

Comment: Raghvender i am new in react. I just want to see results on console

Comment: No buddy, that is definitely not the way how react works. You can first get knowledge about the states in react and then continue

Comment: Thanks Raghvender for your help and advice.